# Show embed URL (iframe) as a string on page

Tags: html, urlencode, url-encoding

I am trying to provide my visitors with a way to copy a video (youtube) embed URL. But of course when I add the embed string to my page it actually embeds the video. I tried to encode the URL but the characters that make up the special characters show.

**This is what I have currently:**

```
<div id="intro_url">%3Ciframe+width%3D%22560%22+height%3D%22315%22+src%3D%22https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fembed%2xxxxxxxxg%22+frameborder%3D%220%22+allow%3D%22autoplay%3B+encrypted-media%22+allowfullscreen%3E%3C%2Fiframe%3E</div>
```

**I was hoping the user would see something like:**

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/TnxxxxxxXg" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

but they get the html encoded version.

**Question:** Is it possible to show an iframe URL without actually adding an iframe to your page?

Comment: Are you wanting just the URL, or to copy the entire `iframe` embed code?

Comment: The entire iframe embed code. I want to show the user the whole thing so they can copy and paste to embed the iframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your use case, its simple enough to replace the literal characters `<` and `>` (which is what signals/triggers html parsing of tags) with the html entities for those characters (i.e. `&lt;` and `$gt;`)

Run my code snippet below and you'll see it renders the raw string that we expect our users to copy. (And if you try copying this into an html page, you'll see the embedded youtube video appear as we expect)

```html
&lt;iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/TnxxxxxxXg" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;
```